# Fetch API doesn't work with non-English characters in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to send POST request to API using JavaScript Fetch API. Everything works fine in Chrome, FF, IE 11 (use polyfill) but doesn't work in Microsoft Edge (Console & Network tabs are empty). It works only when I send latin text as params. For example when I run this code:

```js
fetch(API_URL, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ str: '테스트'})
})
.then((data) => console.log(data))
.catch((err) => {
  console.error('fetch error:', error);
  throw error;
});
```

It doesn't do anything, but when I change value of "str" to "some latin text" then it works fine (sends correct request to API & receive response).

Issue on Microsoft website: [fetch() with unicode characters in request body fails with TypeMismatchError](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8475223/)

Comment: What if you set encoding headers?

Comment: @diegoaguilar what exactly headers do you mean?

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? Does your server receive any request?

Answer (score 2):

Internally, JavaScript strings are encoded as UTF-16. It looks like Edge does not convert to another encoding by default and throws a `TypeMismatchError` if it deems your body not compatible to the configured (or assumed?) `Content-type`.

A fix for this issue is to escape all non-ASCII characters in the JSON representation of the payload:

```
function encodePayload(payload) {
    return JSON.stringify(payload).
        replace(/[\u007F-\uFFFF]/g, function (c) {
            return "\\u" + ("0000" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).substr(-4);
        });
}

fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: encodePayload({ str: '테스트'})
})
```